# Does ping validate icmp checksum?

Tags: ping

ICMP messages contain checksums: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc792

Does `ping` validate the checksums when receiving an echo reply message?

I don't see a note about it in the man page.

I'm using Fedora 27.

Comment: TBH the reason I'm asking is because I'm writing a program that needs to compute the checksum but I don't know how to check if I'm doing it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does.

From the [source code](https://github.com/iputils/iputils/blob/9f7f1d4c4fd4fd90d2c5e66d6deb7f87f2eb1cea/ping.c#L1081):

```
csfailed = in_cksum((unsigned short *)icp, cc, 0);
```

Although it does not seem to check the csfailed when the `icp->type == ICMP_ECHOREPLY`.

If you just want to see the algorithm for the checksum, check the [source code](https://github.com/iputils/iputils/blob/9f7f1d4c4fd4fd90d2c5e66d6deb7f87f2eb1cea/ping.c#L1186) for `unsigned short in_cksum` and following.

Comment: so does that mean if the checksum is not valid, there is no indication?

Comment: There is a part that checks whether the ICMP type is "Parameter Problems", but this looks like the incoming packet has this information in the header. You should just give it a try, with the source code you can simply forge a "wrong" checksum to be sent.